# Attach more than one document using in a rich text field

Tags: lotusscript

For my project, every time I click on generate button, will run an LotusScript agent to create a ".pdf" file inside "attachment" rich text field.

Here is my script for inserting on one document:

```
' ...

Dim oitem As NotesRichTextItem, eo As NotesEmbeddedObject, path$, template
path = Environ$("TEMP") + "\"
template = ""
Set oitem = setdoc.Getfirstitem("AttachmentCert")
If oitem.Type = RICHTEXT Then
    ForAll o In oitem.Embeddedobjects
        Set eo = o
        If eo.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT Then
            template = path + eo.Source
            If Dir$(template, 0) <> "" Then Kill template
            Call eo.Extractfile(template)
            Exit ForAll 
        End If
    End ForAll
End If

' ...

result = path + "Certificate of Compentency for " + names + ".pdf"
Set rtitem = New NotesRichTextItem(doc, "License_Cert")
Call rtitem.Embedobject(EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", result)
```

Problem facing: if I want to attach more document into a rich text field how can I do it?

I try this code, but it's not working:

```
 If doc.hasItem("License_Cert") Then
    Set rtItem = doc.getFirstItem("License_Cert")
    ' Add a couple of lines to the rich text field before re-attaching the file
    Call rtItem.addNewLine(2)
 Else
    Set rtItem = New notesRichTextItem(doc, "License_Cert")
 End If
```

Now it duplicates the same name field, is it ok?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The relevant line is `Call rtitem.Embedobject(EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", result)`, you need to repeat that one with different values for "result" (the path to the file to attach)...

Comment: just upload an image for it using  : add newline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append more than one attachment to a richtext- item you simply do that. Your code would look like this

```
If doc.hasItem("License_Cert") Then
    Set rtItem = doc.getFirstItem("License_Cert")
    ' Add a couple of lines to the rich text field before re-attaching   the file
    Call rtItem.addNewLine(2)
Else
    Set rtItem = New notesRichTextItem(doc, "License_Cert")
End If

result = path + "Certificate of Compentency for " + names + ".pdf"
Call rtitem.Embedobject(EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", result)
result = path + "Some other pdf.pdf"
Call rtitem.Embedobject(EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", result)
```

It is totally normal for Notes to create multiple items with the same name, if the size of the content is larger than a specific value, just check the "Body" item in any bigger mail...